# FastMail account and Online Accounts

Tags: release-juno, pantheon-mail

I entered my FastMail credentials into online accounts and it appears that my account is synced to the Mail app. But when I open Mail I still get a prompt to enter my credentials. What's the story?

Comment: I get this too. And considering it didn't seem to work, I dont see the advantage of setting it up here over using the "Other" field in the Mail app. AND its not clear why there is no "Fastmail" option in the Mail app sign-up when it professes to be implemented as a system preference. You'd think you could open Mail, enter the credentials, and it would add it to "Online Accounts" in the system settings.

Comment: I would suggest creating an issue here https://github.com/elementary/mail/issues